# check datetime falling between 2 dates

Tags: c#, date, c#-4.0

I have to check datetime falling between this dates. I have 2 old dates and 2 new dates and basically need to check whether it's a match or not.

```
DateTime old_start_Dt = Convert.ToDateTime("07/28/2014 3:30:00 AM");
DateTime old_end_Dt = Convert.ToDateTime("07/28/2014 4:00:00 AM");

DateTime new_start_Dt = Convert.ToDateTime("07/28/2014 3:45:00 AM");
DateTime new_end_Dt = Convert.ToDateTime("07/28/2014 5:00:00 AM");

//above dates example should found match.

bool _matchfound = false;

if ((new_start_Dt >= old_start_Dt || new_start_Dt <= old_start_Dt)
   && (new_end_Dt >= old_end_Dt || new_end_Dt <= old_end_Dt))
{
    _matchfound = true;
}
```

Any guess what I am wrong here in my logic?

Comment: shouldn't it be just `new_start_Dt >= old_start_Dt && new_end_Dt <= old_end_Dt` if you want it be inside the old dates

Comment: Your check isn't actually checking anything - for *any* pair of dates, `x >= y || x <= y` is going to be true, and you've got that twice...

Comment: are you trying to find if the current datetime, `var now = DateTime.Now;` falls between these dates?

Comment: Why should your two examples be considered matches?  What is the criteria?  It isn't that they're the same, because they're not; the times are different.

Comment: my requirement. i have appointment in my system before i create new appointment i am checking with old appointment if it's falls any old appoint before i create new appointment ihave to validate. Lets say i have old appointment 9am - 10 am. if i want to create another new appointment 9:15 - 9:45 it should not allow because old appointment already booked that time.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your `if` statement will always be true. Consider that you are testing

```
new >= old || new <= old
```

Well, one of those *has* to be true no matter what. So both parts of the `if` statement will be true regardless of what values your dates have.

I'm not sure exactly what you're going for, but if you want to test that the new range is inside the old one, this should work:

```
if (new_start_Dt >= old_start_Dt && // new starts after old starts
    new_start_Dt < old_end_Dt &&    // new starts before old ends
    new_end_Dt > old_start_Dt &&    // new ends after old starts
    new_end_Dt <= old_end_Dt &&     // new ends before old ends
    old_start_Dt < old_end_Dt &&    // old start is before old end
    new_start_Dt <= new_end_Dt &&)  // new start is before new end
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for you reply. i tested one case it's failing.DateTime old_start_Dt = Convert.ToDateTime("07/28/2014 5:00:00 PM");
DateTime old_end_Dt = Convert.ToDateTime("07/28/2014 5:30:00 PM");
DateTime new_start_Dt = Convert.ToDateTime("07/28/2014 5:15:00 PM");
DateTime new_end_Dt = Convert.ToDateTime("07/28/2014 6:00:00 PM");Since the date fallen in between my case should be match but above logic doesn't work for me.

Comment: No it doesn't—`new_end_Dt` is after `old_end_Dt`.

Comment: if (new_start_Dt >= old_start_Dt && new_start_Dt < old_end_Dt &&new_end_Dt > old_start_Dt &&new_end_Dt <= old_end_Dt &&old_start_Dt < old_end_Dt && new_start_Dt <= new_end_Dt ){_matchfound = true;} My requirement should match. if it's fallen any date inbetween old Date